# Unity OnTriggerEnter2D cannot be reused

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I Have a problem with the OnTriggerEnter2D eventTrigger.

The main problem is to have the OntriggerEnter2D activate whenever the same object(s) re enter the Circle Collider 2D.

Currently I have 3 object that can interact, lets call them A1, A2 and B1.
 When B1 has entered A1, it works. When B1 has entered A2, it works. But when B1 re-enter A1 it doesnt work. And this also includes if A2 is entered at the start.

All i could find was unity explaining:
"Notes: Trigger events will be sent to disabled MonoBehaviours, to allow enabling Behaviours in response to collisions."
(http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html)

If it's the case that it just totaly deactivate the trigger for OnTriggerEnter2D, is there some kinda way to work around it to make it work like a "OnTriggerEnter2D"?

I know about the OnTriggerStay2D but for me it would just be a waste of process power and at the same time a stupidly poor solution.

Comment: Why would OnTriggerStay be a poor solution?

Comment: OnTriggerEnter2D should be triggered again for the same 2 objects if they stopped overlapping and then overlapped again. If that's not happening, file a bug report by going to Help->Report a Bug.

Answer (score 1):

Depending what you mean by re-enter. If your object never fully detach apart,  you won't have a new call to OnTriggerEnter2D.

In that case OnTriggerStay2D is the way to go if you want notification of your object staying on top of another one after initial OnTriggerEnter2D call